# How can I index child object properties in an array using ydn-db-fulltext?

Tags: javascript, full-text-search, indexeddb, full-text-indexing, ydn-db

I'm using Ydn-Db-Fulltext to allow users to search a local database of contacts in an HTML5 app. So far, when it comes to searching for names of people, it works great, is smart, and returns results instantly.

Here's an example of a contact object that contains an array of contact Methods:

```
{
   "source": "COMPANY",
   "ownerPin": "12345",
   "name": "brian wilkins",
   "dateUpdated": "2014-03-18T14:41:05.217Z",
   "dateAdded": "2014-03-18T14:41:05.217Z",
   "isFavorite": false,
   "socialId": "54321",
   "id": "1",
   "deleted": false,
   "edited": false,
   "favorite": false,
   "contactMethods": [
    {
     "id": "4321",
     "contactKey": "12321",
     "contactId": "1",
     "value": "brian.wilkins@geemail.com",
     "kind": "email",
     "ownerPin": "12345",
     "isPrimary": false
    },
    {
     "id": "5432",
     "contactKey": "2",
     "contactId": "1",
     "kind": "phone",
     "ownerPin": "12345",
     "isPrimary": false
    },
    {
     "id": "23",
     "contactKey": "333",
     "contactId": "1",
     "value": "112345",
     "kind": "extension",
     "ownerPin": "12345",
     "isPrimary": false
    }
   ]
  }
```

To create the index on the "name" property, I setup the fullTextCatalog as follows:

```
fullTextCatalogs: [{
      name: 'name',
      lang: 'en',
      sources: [
        {
          storeName: 'contacts',
          keyPath: 'id',
          weight: 1.0
        }, {
          storeName: 'contacts',
          keyPath: 'name',
          weight: 0.5
        }
      ]
    }],
    stores: [
      {
        name: 'contacts',
        keyPath: 'id',
        autoIncrement: true
      }
    ]
  };
  this.db = new ydn.db.Storage('thedatabase', db_schema);
```

I can search by name or by id (the key) and get a list of contacts that match. Little appears to be stored in memory. Every search queries the local backing indexedDB database.

The challenge is that I also want to be able to search based on email address and extension, which are stored in the contactMethods property inside an array of contactMethods. The "value" property is where we store the email address and/or extension depending on the contactMethod type.

I tried adding contactMethods as a secondary searchable object store, but this resulted in searches for "Brian" returning two results, both the contact containing the name, and the contactMethod containing the email address.  Ideally, I'd want to take the contactId (foreign key to the contact) and use it to pull the actual contact object, but it seems like this could create very expensive overhead and negate the benefits of this great search tool.

Is there a way to index object properties that are not at the parent level?  How can I approach this in a way that would scale and not eat up all of the resources?

```
  this.db.get(entry.storeName, entry.primaryKey).done(function(x) {
    this.textContent += ' [Full name: ' + x.name + ']';  // this is in the contact
    this.textContent += ' [email: ' + x.value + ']';     // but this is in the contactMethod
  }, span);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tagging help @Kyaw. I'm reading into the [schema documentation](http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/schema.html) more, and it sounds like a parent->child one-one-to-many relationship with out-of-line keys as arrays is what I need, where one key element is the name and the other is the email address, or something like that. I'll definitely self-answer if I figure it out before someone else does. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to index object properties that are not at the parent level?

`keyPath` can refer to deep object property by using dotted notation. For example, you could specify `contactMethods.value` to index email, but unfortunately it does not work with array value - as in this case.

So, obvious choice is keeping `contactMethods` record in separate object store using parent-child relationship. Since ydn-db currently does not support `embedded` attribute in the schema, you will have to load all child records when loading parent object.

Alternatively, [IndexedDB v2](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GElSszU_i2ytskrdBdNrJTDFog-yC7VrHellgQg65IQ/edit) may have virtual index generated by a function expression. You can use in ydn-db by `generator` in index schema, for example:

```
 stores: [
   {
     name: 'contacts',
     keyPath: 'id',
     autoIncrement: true,
     indexes: [{
       name: '$emails',
       multiEntry: true,
       generator: function(record) {
         return record.contactMethods.map(function(x) {return x.value};
       })
     }]
   }
 ]
```

One thing to note though, the generated field `$emails` will appear when you load the data. It likely will be removed from the record so as to match with v2 spec.

We are using this generator index heavily in multiple projects, so I will fix bug.

Indexing `id` and email address in full text search is convenient, but does not make sense because phonetic base full text search will be index them as it is without normalization.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying about the $emails appearing and getting removed. I see the index, but nothing is in it. I put a console.log statement in the generator and I can see x.value has the data. Is this something that must wait for the bugfix you're referring to?  Thank you!

Comment: no bug, generator is working. you have to specify `$emails` in full text catalog source. If you find bug, please file an issue.

Comment: Okay, so I can't tell if Chrome uses indexedDB v2 or not. I can tell generator is running, but even with $emails in the fullTextCatalog the index isn't being populated. So I'm assuming that's because Chrome doesn't use indexedDB v2. Thus, this must mean I have to use option 1, which is to create a separate store for contactMethods. From looking at the ydn-db source, I'm assuming generate is supposed to just add the indexed property to the parent object so ydn-db can populate the index?  I tried that manually using a single "email" property with a comma-separated list of emails,

Comment: [cont'd] but I'm not sure the search was able to work correctly since it was impossible to do an exact match.

Comment: indexing email to full text search will not work. Just use regular index after normalization.

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you, I think I just have one last clarification:  Is this one of those situations where I'd use db.search for fulltext but then if I detect an email address in the input box I'd use db.values(new ydn.db.IndexValueIterator instead?  I was thinking of just going that route so I can return the contact, regardless of what I'm searching for. If I do that, won't the email address have to be an exact match in order to return any results?

Comment: Yes. To query by prefix key, use `IndexValueIterator.where('store name', '$email', 'starts', 'prefixkey')`